# I scraped my rim what should I do?

Tags: tires, wheels, rav4

I made a u turn and scraped my rim [image]

Comment: Other than replace it, the best thing to do is get it checked by a professional who can see it in person.  There may be cracks in the metal that you haven't noticed.

Comment: ...and that's why I don't like aluminum rims. In the same situation, steel bends instead and is easily inspected and bent back if even needed.   Call around to scrap yards and tell them what car and wheel you have, they can get a match.